# The function getWiFiAddress() always returns nil?

Tags: ios, swift, ip-address

The function always returns nil, if i print interface name there is no name "en0". i need to get the local ipaddress of the device, how can i do it??

```
func getWiFiAddress() -> String? {
var address : String?

// Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

// For each interface ...
for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
    let interface = ifptr.pointee

    // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
    let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
    if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

        // Check interface name:
        let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
        if  name == "en0" {

            // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
            var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
            getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                        &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                        nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
            address = String(cString: hostname)
        }
    }
}
freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

return address
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any value to ifaddr.

Answer (score 0):

instead of en0 i changed it to en1 and it gets my local ip address....the reason is en0 is for wired or ethernet, for wireless we need to use en1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> lo0

for local address

```
func getWiFiAddress() -> String? {
    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

    // For each interface ...
    for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let interface = ifptr.pointee

        // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
        let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
        if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

            // Check interface name:
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
            if  name == "lo0" {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                            &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
                return String(cString: hostname)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: lo0 is for loopback interfaces...if we need to get local LAN ip we need to use en0 for wired network and en1 for wireless...